# Django Password Reset

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Django and trying to build an authentication framework for my Django app and its falling over when I try and build the password_reset and password_reset_done apps. I am using Django builtin framework and have not customized to any extent

These are my urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views



  url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="registration/password_reset.html"), name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password_reset_done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^password_reset_confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^password_reset_complete/$',auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name="password_reset_complete"),
```

This is the error message I get

```
NoReverseMatch at /partners/password_reset/
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/partners/password_reset/
Django Version: 2.1.1
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 622
Python Executable:  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\protectandserve',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2018.5-py3.7.egg']
Server time:    Thu, 4 Oct 2018 07:49:46 +0000


Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\templates\registration\password_reset_email.html, error at line 6

Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
1   {% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
2   {% blocktrans %}You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}
3   
4   {% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
5   {% block reset_link %}
6   {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
7   {% endblock %}
8   {% trans "Your username, in case you've forgotten:" %} {{ user.get_username }}
9   
10  {% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}
11  
12  {% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}
13  
14  {% endautoescape %}
15  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGmJT.png
```

[image: screen grab 1]

[image: screen grab 2]

Comment: How do you think someone can reproduce this error if the question lacks... code?

Comment: Please post your `password_reset_confirm` definition.

Comment: please can you specify what additional code you need over and above that stated above please @ZF007 . I have not defined password_reset_confirm as I understood this as builtin

Comment: I understood auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view() as the builtin function with the definition

Comment: code = "definition" to be specific in this case. As Vishal mentioned too.

Comment: Is this url.py file is of another app like  - accounts...or of your main project  ?

Comment: did you import the builtin function in the urls.py? Something like `from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views`?

Comment: the url.py is in another app called - partners .... Its not in the main project

Comment: from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Copy `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\templates\registration\password_reset_email.html` to `partners\templates\registration\`
2. Edit line 6 of the file `partners\templates\registration\password_reset_email.html` to

   ```
   {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'partners:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
   ```
3. Update your urls.py to point to right template:

   ```
   url(
       r'^password_reset/$',
       auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
           template_name="registration/password_reset.html",
           email_template_name="registration/password_reset_email.html",
           success_url=reverse_lazy('partners:password_reset_done'), # might be required
       ),
       name='password_reset'
   ),
   ```

Comment: Thankyou @Vaibhav Vishal . I seem to get an error TemplateDoesNotExist at /partners/password_reset/.  partners/registration/password_reset_email.html

Comment: @Vailbhav Vishal I have added 2 screen grabs to my question to demonstrate my structure. Let me know if you need any further code

Comment: THANK-YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU . You are legend !

Comment: Thank you - This was EXACTLY what solved my week-long problem!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the urls.py is of partners, so reverse call should be to partners, change in your template 
`{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}`
to `{% url 'partners:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}`.

`partners` is app name.
This will work.