# NoReverseMatch - Resetting password in Django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have found many similar questions to this issue. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716578/noreversematch-error-in-password-reset-functionality-django#) was one of them, but it didn't solve my problem, so I will ask my own question.

I'm making a password reset page on my website. But when I go to `http://localhost:8000/users/reset-password` and enter my email and clicks on 'Reset my password', then Django throws a `NoReverseMatch` error at me.
The error is:

```
NoReverseMatch at /users/reset-password/
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I believe there's something wrong with how I write my urlpatterns.

I've tried:

- Making my own views and templates.
- Rewriting all my urlpatterns.

## My Code

**urls.py**:

```
"""Defines URL Patterns for users."""

from django.urls import re_path
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    LoginView, PasswordResetView, PasswordResetConfirmView,
    PasswordResetDoneView,
)

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Login Page.
    re_path(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'),
            name='login'),

    # Logout Page.
    re_path(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),

    # Registration Page.
    re_path(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),

    # Password reset Page.
    re_path(r'^password_reset/$', PasswordResetView.as_view(
        # This is the only line I added in this file.
        template_name='users/password_reset_email.html'
    ),
            name='password_reset'),

    # Password reset done Page.
    re_path(r'^password_reset/done/$', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
            name='password_reset_done'),

    # Password reset confirm Page.
    re_path(r'^password_reset/confirm/'
            + '(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
            PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
            name='password_reset_confirm'),
]
```

My *own* `users/password_reset_email.html`:

```
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
{% blocktrans %}You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}

{% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'users:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
{% trans "Your username, in case you've forgotten:" %} {{ user.get_username }}

{% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}

{% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}

{% endautoescape %}
```

**Update:**

I got something right. Now I get a `NoReverseMatch at /users/password_reset/
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': '', 'token': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/password_reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$']`. I got to this error by using my *own* template of djangos `password_reset_email.html`, where I modified the line: `{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}` to `{% url 'users:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}`. Now i'm almost certain that i'm just writing my urls or regexes wrong.

I have edited my question to show the new code.

Comment: Have you included these urlpatterns to the main urlpatterns?

Comment: Yes in my project folder, i have included all urls starting with /users/ Like this: `re_path(r'^users/$', include(('users.urls', 'users'), namespace='users'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it.
Here is the answer to the problem.

Now I get a `ConnectionRefusedError`, which means that I now only need to set up an SMTP Server for emails, and then it should work! The thing I was missing all the time was, that I wasn't pointing out what email template I wanted to use. I just set the email template as *the* template, so Django couldn't render it correctly. Here is the updated code for `urls.py` where `path(r'password-reset/')` is changed:

```
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy
import django.contrib.auth.views as auth_views

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Login Page.
    path(r'login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(
        template_name='users/login.html'
    ),
         name='login'),

    # Logout Page.
    path(r'logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),

    # Registration Page.
    path(r'register/', views.register, name='register'),

    # Password reset page.
    path(r'password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        email_template_name='users/password_reset_email.html',
        success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_done')
    ), name='password_reset'),

    # Password reset done page.
    path(r'password-reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
         name='password_reset_done'),

    # Password reset confirm page.
    path(r'password-reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
         name='password_reset_confirm')
]
```

Everything else is correct.
I got the answer from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52643357/10191353).